# Selection sort issue given array range

Tags: c++, sorting, selection

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// copy the swap function of lab10a
// copy the smallest function of lab10b
int sorting(int a[], int left, int right) {
    // parameter a[] is the array to be sorted
    // parameter left is the left index
    // parameter right is the right index
    // the function returns the index i, where a[i] is the
    // smallest value in a[left..right]
    // if (left > right || left < 0 || right < 0)
    //error cases and return 1 for failure
    // use a loop to iterate each index from left to right
    // and let i be the variable in the iteration
    // interchange the values of a[i] and a[ smallest(a, i, right) ]
    if (left > right || left < 0 || right < 0) {
        cout << "Error index out of bounds" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    int temp;
    int index = left;
    for (int i = index; i <= right; i++) {
        int j = i;
        while (j <= right) {
            if (a[j] < a[index])
                index = j;
            j++;
        }
        temp = a[index];
        a[index] = a[i];
        a[i] = temp;
    }
    return 0; //for success
}
// Program to test sorting function
//-----------------------------------------
int main()
{
    int a[] = {9,1,5,7,4,2,6,0,8,3};

    // test case one
    sorting(a, 1, 5);
    cout << " The value in A[1..5] is sorted nondecreasingly\n";
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        cout << "a[" << i << "] = " << a[i] << endl;
    // test case two
    sorting(a, 0, 9);
    cout << " The value in A[0..9] is sorted nondecreasingly\n";
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        cout << "a[" << i << "] = " << a[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am having trouble with this sorting algorithm. When I run this it seems to work very oddly and I can't seem to pinpoint where the issue arises. The part that I know where the issue is located starts within the sorting function at the first for loop. The tricky part of this is that the function asks for bounds on the array to do the selection sort so that has made it hard to grasp since I am not an experienced programmer.

Comment: Step thru your sorting loop in a debugger.  You should be able to spot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical error in your program.You need to update index with current value of i with every iteration.

try this, it works fine :

```
int temp;
int index ;
for (int i = left; i <= right; i++) {
    index =i;
    int j = i+1;
    while (j <= right) {
        if (a[j] < a[index])
            index = j;
        j++;
    }
    if(index != i){
    temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[index];
    a[index] = temp;
  }
}
```